# If checkbox is checked div appears

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Im new to rails/Jquery and I got a problem. My objective is: If the `checkbox(credit_card_fields)` is checked, the `div (credit_card_fields)` appears.

This is my script:

```
<script>
$("input[type='checkbox']#pay_with_card").on('change', function(){
  $('credit_card_fields').toggle();
});
</script>
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(:estudante, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :pay_with_card? %>
  <%= f.check_box :pay_with_card,{}, "Yes", "No"%>
  <div id="credit_card_fields" style="display:none;">
    <%= f.label :card_number %> <%= f.text_field :card_number %>
    <%= f.label :mail %> <%= f.text_field :mail %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: `$("input[type='checkbox']#pay_with_card").on('change', function () {
    $('credit_card_fields').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#pay_with_card").change(function(){
  $("#credit_card_fields").toggle($(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<!-- THIS HTML IS FOR DEMO PURPOSES ONLY! -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>pay_with_card?</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="estudante[pay_with_card]" id="pay_with_card" checked="checked">
<div id="credit_card_fields">
  <label>card_number</label>
  <input type="text" name="estudante[card_number]">
  <label>mail</label>
  <input type="text" name="estudante[mail]">
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to use any other qualifiers in your selector when you use an id. [**There can be only one.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqcLjcSloXs)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass argument to `.toggle()` method:

```
$(function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox']#pay_with_card").on('change', function(){
   $('#credit_card_fields').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
  });
});
```

Comment: like this?

`$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#credit_card_fields').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});`

Comment: Can you share the fiddle with relevant  markup and js code.

Comment: can you add rendered html.

Comment: Only display the checkbox "Pay with card?"

Comment: You have a simple syntax error in your pastebin `$(function(){` is missing a closing `});` I would recommend you [learn to use the browser console](http://wickedlysmart.com/hfjsconsole/).

Comment: oh sorry. I changed and still nothing

Comment: as i said already. can help only when you share the rendered div and checkbox html

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the [jQuery ready function](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). Try this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $("input[type='checkbox']#pay_with_card").on('change', function(){
     $('credit_card_fields').toggle();
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If the script is inline and placed at the bottom of the page you don't really need ready. This answer just comes off as rep fishing. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @max well, in his link http://pastebin.com/LbAxaPep the script is clearly in the head, so I think my answer is valid. Thanks for the explanation though.

Comment: Then its fully valid. +1